# Why is the field not overridden?

Tags: java

I have following two classes.

```
   class A{
    int p;
    A(){p=100;}
    void printMe(){System.out.println("A");}
   }

   class B extends A{
    int p;
    B(){p=10000;}
    void printMe(){System.out.println("B");}
    }
```

When I create a object in this way,

```
    A c=new B();
    System.out.println(c.p);
    c.printMe();
```

I hope it would print 10000 as p value but it prints 100. Why is that?

Comment: because you can´t override variables

Comment: Because these are 2 different variables. You cant get to both by casting to A or B